# Android start activity by selecting item on listview and place data sent with intent on another list view

Tags: android

Hi i have a problem i would like on my android app that uses a list once an item is clicked on the list the id is captured and a query run the data received is then placed in an intent and a new activity is started and the data placed in a another list any help how this can be achieved with an example if possible

Answer (score 1):

```
yourlist.OnItemClickListener(listenerOflistView);

private OnItemClickListener listenerOflistView = new OnItemClickListener() {
    private String getSelectedItemOfList;

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> view, View view1, int pos, long arg3) {
        Intent in = new Intent(Context, nextActivity.class);
        String getSelectedItemOfList = mylist.get(pos).toString();
        in.putExtras("AnythingName", getSelectedItemOfList);
        startActivity(in);
    }
}
```

In another activity:

```
Intent in = getIntent();
in.getStringextras("AnythingName");
```

then, you get the value of another activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve by using `OnItemClickListener()` for `ListView`. So that when you click list item you will get the content of `Listview`.

```
yourlist.OnItemClickListener(listenerOflistView);

private OnItemClickListener listenerOflistView = new OnItemClickListener() {
    private String getSelectedItemOfList;

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> view, View view1, int pos, long arg3) {
        getSelectedItemOfList = mylist.get(pos).toString(); 
        // here you will get selected item. And you can perform rest of your task here.
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks the problem is once i've run the query i need all the results to be displayed in another list in another activity which should start immediately after the data is retrieved

Comment: then what's the problem you can start another activity on click event of listview.

Comment: Is the problem that you do not know how to start another actvity, or that the next Lists Content is complexer that one String per Listitem?

Comment: should the list be loaded before i start the intent or after starting the intent